# how to configure dovecot for local network only?

Tags: postfix, dovecot, local-area-network

I have installed postfix, dovecot, mysql, postfixadmin. i only want to configure these packages only to send emails around the local network. Specifically: i have installed outlook on client computers and want configure it with IMAP/POP3 protocol to connect to my mail server on LAN. what configurations should i add? I am running CentOS 6.8 Some of the questions i have are (i hope they dont sound silly):

1. How am i going to create a user account, for local lan network only?
2. How am i going to add that account to outlook?
3. What domain am i going to use? (i havent bought any domain from any registrar)

Please feel free to add anything to clarify the solution.

Comment: Is your postfix/dovecot server installed on a server that is accessible from the Internet, or that can access the Internet? If not, then you can not exchange mails with the Internet. Will you have laptop users that want to access their mails from outside your LAN? What will your users do when they do want to exchange mails with the Internet?

Comment: @Law29 The server is not accessible from the internet. It can access the internet. I am not interested in exchanging mails with the internet. I dont want users to access their mail accounts outside the LAN. I dont want the users to exchange mails with the internet.

Answer (score 2):

If your server is not accessible from the Internet, but can access the Internet, then all you need to do is make sure that a mail sent to the Internet does not go out. There are several ways to do that:

1. do not grant MSA rights to logged-in users. You can have no SASL at all (but instead you could force SASL for everybody, to avoid mail source spoofing). Set postfix mynetworks to 127.0.0.1/32.
2. firewall your server so that it cannot send e-mail to the Internet.
3. set the postfix smarthost to some invalid address.

The first is best since mails sent to outside addresses are refused immediately. You can very well implement all three methods.

You may also want to stop users on your LAN from accessing the Internet directly, but that is another problem.

As for your questions:

1. *How am I going to create a user account, for local lan network only?*: there is no difference, it's a regular account. You need to choose if you are going to use system accounts or virtual mailboxes, and if virtual mailboxes you need to have them in text files or in a database. Use any tutorial for that.
2. *How am I going to add that account to outlook?*: there is no difference, it's a regular account, you need a server and username and password.
3. *What domain am I going to use? (I haven't bought any domain from any registrar)*: you can in theory use any domain you want, but you should either use a domain you do own (that you have bought from a registrar) or a subdomain of such a domain (if you've bought `example.com` for your company then use `internal.example.com` or `private.example.com` or `secure.example.com`, you get the idea), or an invalid domain such as `example.local`.

Comment: what about dovecot and postfix configurations? i dont have a domain. what should i do? should i create a local domain? how?

Comment: @redi You can't expect a full tutorial. This is a question and answer site. You are expected to figure some things out on your own and ask specific questions when you need help.

Comment: Thanks @redi The only unusual aspect of this question is the "no Internet interaction part", so that is what I described. The rest is bog-standard postfix and dovecot that one can find in the product documentation and in any number of how-tos, and that (where I live) network technicians have in their first-year curriculum, so I'm not going there.